# Want to generate tabular output when solving two equations in two unknowns

Tags: equation-solving

I have two functions:

$\qquad f1 = a1(x) + b1(x)$

$\qquad f2 = a2(x) + g\, b2(x)$

I am attempting to find roots with

```
FindRoot[{f1, f2}, {{x, x0},{g, g0}}]
```

I need `x` and `g` in tabular form.  The value of `g` changes for every `x`.  I need a tabular output.  Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked at `Table`?

Comment: @MarcoB:Yes I looked at table.  I am getting an error message telling the value of g0  in search specification {g,g0} is not a array of numbers.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you were to edit your post to include code that could serve as a minimal **working** example of your problem. As it is currently posted you have not given sufficient context for me (and many others who might want to help you) to work on your problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have stated your problem correctly, you should take a completely different approach.  Note that given `x`, `f2` is linear in `g`.  Thus you can characterize the root directly:

```
g = Function[x, -a2[x]/b2[x]]
```

Now you can just plot this over the desired range, which will be much more informative than a table.  However, if you want a tabular form, just create it by mapping over a range or over an interval division or whatever, and then use `TableForm` to display it.  E.g.,

```
TableForm[{#,g[#]}&/@Range[-10,10]]
```